# Windows Server incorrectly detecting wired network as "metered", even though it's set not to be

Tags: networking, windows-server

I have a weird issue where Windows Server 2022 is detecting my ethernet (VMware powered) as "metered" despite my not setting it as metered, and the system being on a Verizon FiOS Business network line.

The system reports it as "metered" even though I set it to "off", and is affecting updates.  That in turn affects my ability to set up a WSUS server on my network as well.

Has anyone seen this type of issue and come across a fix?  Note that I went through network reset and checked drivers and the drivers are up to date (VMXNET 3 so VMware Tools).